# how to plot time related data when the time data have been settled as index?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time

After settled the time data as index by `dft = dft.set_index('c_time')`I then resample the data by month by `dftm = dft.resample('M').sum().to_period('M')` and the data looks like this

```
print(dftm['topic0'].head())
c_time
2012-03    0.0
2012-04    1.0
2012-05    0.0
2012-06    0.0
2012-07    0.0
Freq: M, Name: topic0, dtype: float64
```

how to set the resampled time data (bu month) as the x axis? I failed to do it by this:

```
x = dftq.index
y1 = dftq['topic0']
# Plot Line1 (Left Y Axis)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(16,9), dpi= 80)
ax1.plot(x, y1, color='tab:red')




ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be one of the cases for matplotlib's date2num function:

```
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
x = date2num(dftq.index)
```

However, did you simply try

```
dftq.topic0.plot()
```

?

---

***EDIT:*** *(for question: how to plot by selecting a given scope of time?)*

You can do that either by already indexing the data to be plotted with `.loc`

```
dftm.loc['2012-04':'2012-06'].plot()

# or

dftm.topic0.loc['2012-04':'2012-06'].plot()
```

or by adjusting the axis limits of the whole plot afterwards:

```
ax = dftm.plot()
ax.set_xlim('2012-04', '2012-06')

# or

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dftm.plot()
plt.xlim('2012-04', '2012-06')
```

---

***supplemental:*** *(regarding plotting with matplotlib api and date2num)*

The first proposal via matplotlib and its `date2num` would also work, if the time index is not changed from type datetime to period.
But still: to have no integer numbers at the x axis tickes but nicely formatted dates, you would have to add sth like

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
xfmt = DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
```

Comment: the latter one worked! I can't imagine it's such a easy way : )

Comment: but how to plot by selecting a given scope of time? such as' 2017-4:2017-6'